# Adobe Acrobat API in Python

Tags: python, acrobat, win32com, acrobat-sdk

**System:**

```
Python 3.6
Windows 10
```

**Goal:**

Use the Adobe Acrobat API to use the "Save As" feature to save a pdf to jpegs.

Note: For my purposes I cannot use Wand or other packages.

**Resources:**

- [Adobe_API_Documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FIAC_API_OLE_Objects%2FAcroExch_PDDoc.htm%23IX_AcroExch_PDDoc&rhsearch=com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg)
- [Implementation_Example 1](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/11/23/Automating-Adobe-Acrobat-Pro-with-python/)
- [Error_Handling_Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9383307/)
- [VBA_Example](https://www.myengineeringworld.net/2013/03/vba-macro-to-convert-pdf-files-into.html)

**Current Code:**

```
import winerror
import win32com
from win32com.client.dynamic import Dispatch, ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT

ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT.append(winerror.E_NOTIMPL)

my_dir = r"path\\to\\example\\"
my_pdf = "example.pdf"

os.chdir(my_dir)
src = os.path.abspath(my_pdf)

pdDoc = Dispatch("AcroExch.PDDoc")
pdDoc.Open(src)

jsObject = pdDoc.GetJSObject()

jsObject.SaveAs(os.path.abspath('./output_example.jpeg'), "com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg")
```

**Issue:**
*jsObject* is Null
Resulting in the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-9c82c454eb2a> in <module>()
----> 1 jsObject.SaveAs(os.path.abspath('./output_example.jpeg'), "com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SaveAs'
```

**Error Documentation Notes:**

```
GetJSObject
Gets a dual interface to the JavaScript object associated with the PDDoc. This allows automation clients full access to both built-in and user-defined JavaScript methods available in the document. For more information on working with JavaScript, see Developing Applications Using Interapplication Communication.

Syntax
LDispatch* GetJSObject();

Returns
The interface to the JavaScript object if the call succeeded, NULL otherwise.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider interfacing with the *AvDoc* object as one of your links show its usage, and then build *pdDoc* and *jsObject* from it. Be sure to also wrap process in a `try/except/finally` block to effectively release COM objects regardless of error.

```
import os    
import winerror
from win32com.client.dynamic import Dispatch, ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT

ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT.append(winerror.E_NOTIMPL)

my_dir = r"C:\\path\\to\\example\\"
my_pdf = "example.pdf"

os.chdir(my_dir)
src = os.path.abspath(my_pdf)

try:
    AvDoc = Dispatch("AcroExch.AVDoc")    

    if AvDoc.Open(src, ""):            
        pdDoc = AvDoc.GetPDDoc()
        jsObject = pdDoc.GetJSObject()
        jsObject.SaveAs(os.path.join(my_dir, 'output_example.jpeg'), "com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg")

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

finally:        
    AvDoc.Close(True)

    jsObject = None
    pdDoc = None
    AvDoc = None
```